# how to get number of tags when user share post on facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api

> I want the javascript or PHP code to get total number of tags when user share the post on facebook.
>   I am allowing particular user to share my post on facebook but he must tag at least three people when he shares the post on facebbook. In this case i need to get the number of tags when user share the post on facebook.

Comment: Do you mean tags as in HTML tags, or when somebody tags a friend? Either way I'm not sure there is such a thing.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: need to get total number of tags ,when somebody tags a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i found the solution myself. It may not be proper but i have made use of it very properly. And it will help a lot. Please check the link https://github.com/andyideologi/count_tag_fb_friends